# Extract string from first character till string pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, string

I have a implicit file with `**$&*#@**` as field delimiter and `**$#@&***` as record delimiter. Below is an example,

```
100$&*#@200$&*#@50$&*#@Some String$&*#@2016-01-01 101010$#@&*101$&*#@210$&*#@51$&*#@Some String$&*#@2016-02-02 101010$#@&*102$&*#@220$&*#@55$&*#@Some String$&*#@2016-03-03 101010$#@&*
```

I need some command to extract first line from above file for doing the data validation.

Please note that in this case `wc -l` is returning ZERO since it is a continuous stream (implicit file) and therefore I can not use head -1.

Further I will have to extract each field and do a validation like to make sure first three fields are integer and a particular number field is a timestamp with specific format.

Answer (score 0):

I used a variable named `string` to store your example. The below `sed` should split your `string` into lines, and separate fields with `:`. You can pipe it into a `head -1` to get the first line :

```
 echo $string | sed 's/'"$#@&\*"'/\n/g'| sed 's/'"$&\*#@"'/:/g'
```

Then you can use `cut` to get the first three fields from each line and verify whether they are numbers only. An example to test first field :

```
field1="$(echo $new_string | cut -d: -f1 | head -1)"
if [ "$field1" -eq "$field1" ] 2>/dev/null; then
  echo "Integer.
else
  echo "Not integer."
fi
```

You can parse and verify all the values with a loop.
Testing the date might be more complex but doable, probably with regex or so.